# What's the simplest way to get the highest and lowest keys from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
self.mood_scale = {
    '-30':"Panic",
    '-20':'Fear',
    '-10':'Concern',
    '0':'Normal',
    '10':'Satisfaction',
    '20':'Happiness',
    '30':'Euphoria'}
```

I need to set two variables: `max_mood` and `min_mood`, so I can put some limits on a ticker.
What's the easiest way to get the lowest and the highest keys?

Comment: is that valid Dictionary definition? the dictionary should have keys and values.

Comment: Your keys don't have to be strings. They can be integers. This will make it easier to answer your question, too. Also, the syntax is wrong. You don't need the inner braces.

Comment: You have dictionaries within a dictionary. Is this correct?

Comment: Not correct, my mistake. Already corrected it, sorry.

Comment: @SilentGhost An explanation: the question was all messed up, with extra brackets - ilegal - and strings where it was supposed to be ints. I edited and took out the brackets, and later i edited and converted the keys to ints. There wasn't many answers/comments then, so the question wasn't too messy.
I chose the answer which gave me a straight solution, plus, i only accepted the answer after @unwind edited it explaining he didn't notice the string/int confusion.
I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
max_mood = max(self.mood_scale)
min_mood = min(self.mood_scale)
```

Perhaps not the most efficient (since it has to get and traverse the list of keys twice), but certainly very obvious and clear.

UPDATE: I didn't realize your keys were strings. Since it sounds as if that was a mistake, I'll let this stand as is, but do note that it requires keys to be actual integers.

Comment: @Jorge, because you use strings. And `-10` is lexically before `-20`.

Comment: @Jorge: it is using lexicographical ordering of strings. As others have said, you really probably want integer keys. Then you will get the expected order.

Comment: So obvious,innit? I'll go for a boat of caffeine, i think.

Comment: As the keys are in string format, we should convert it to Integers.

Maximum: `max([int(k) for k in self.mood_scale.keys()])`

Minimum: `min([int(k) for k in self.mood_scale.keys()])` should work!

Comment: Just so it's clear (see comment on other answer): no need to call the `keys` method here. You can just do `max(self.mood_scale)`.

Comment: @Thomas: I removed it. I removed it.

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> min(self.mood_scale, key=int)
'-30'
>>> max(self.mood_scale, key=int)
'30'
```

Answer (score 7):

Is that valid Python? I think you mean:

```
mood_scale = {
    '-30':"Panic",
    '-20':'Fear',
    '-10':'Concern',
    '0':'Normal',
    '10':'Satisfaction',
    '20':'Happiness',
    '30':'Euphoria'}

print mood_scale[str(min(map(int,mood_scale)))]
print mood_scale[str(max(map(int,mood_scale)))]
```

Outputs

> Panic 
>    Euphoria

Much better and faster with ints as keys

```
mood_scale = {
    -30:"Panic",
    -20:'Fear',
    -10:'Concern',
    0:'Normal',
    10:'Satisfaction',
    20:'Happiness',
    30:'Euphoria'}

print mood_scale[min(mood_scale))]
print mood_scale[max(mood_scale))]
```

Edit 2:
Is much faster using the iterator

```
print timeit.timeit( lambda: mood_scale[min(mood_scale.keys())])
print timeit.timeit( lambda: mood_scale[min(mood_scale)])
1.05913901329
0.662925004959
```

Another solution could be to keep track of the max/min values upon insertion and simply do
mood_scale.min() / max()

Comment: No need to call `,keys()` in any of the cases; dictionaries are iterables that yield their keys, so `max(mood_scale)` would be fine.

Comment: @Thomas-Wouters
I like it more in the sense of ' Explicit is Better than implicit. '

Comment: Also in the sense of "slow is better than fast", or "more memory is better than less"? :)